# Making packages in IntelliJ-IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I usually use .Net but now I'm playing Scala in IntelliJ 10.5.1. It's interesting how can I make a package which I can import to other projects?

Comment: You mean a library? Like a .jar file?

Comment: Yes it is interesting. What have you tried?

Comment: You can introduce a dependency of one module on other modules. Maybe that's what you mean?

Comment: I want to find the way to import the code that I write earlier in my current project. I have a few classes in one project and I want to reuse them in the other one. It will be perfect if I could write `import my.old.project.CoolClass._`

Comment: Then you have to make the second project dependent from the first project: File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> <Module name> -> Dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a jar file you do that through File->Project Structure->Artifacts hit the + sign choose Jar -> from module with dependencies 
Then you can choose whether you want all the dependencies inside your jar or not
Then you can create the jar via the Build->Build Artifacts menu

When you have a new project you can reference that jar via the dependencies menu mentioned by Christian